# Create a table with default values that use the primary key column in a function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I just dabble in Oracle, so go easy on me if this is basic...I've searched extensively for an answer and the answer doesn't exist, it's not possible, or my searches haven't used the correct terminology.

Anyway, I'm writing DDL that will create a date dimension table. I've got a date key, which is the primary key for the table, that I'm trying to propagate across all the other columns in the table to use as the default value for those columns when a new value is added to the date key column.

Here's a snippet of what I've tried so far, but gave me the error "ORA-00984: column not allowed here":

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_DIM
(
    DATE_KEY  DATE NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT DATE_KEY_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY),
    DAY_NUMBER  NUMBER(2) DEFAULT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE_KEY,'DD')),
    DAY_NAME  VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT TO_CHAR(DATE_KEY,'Day')
)
```

If I substitute `SYSDATE` for `DATE_KEY`, I don't return any errors. But, assuming everything that I'm conceptualizing comes to fruition, I will need to insert a more specific date than sysdate...and just for clarity's sake, no other columns would be update-able.

Ultimately, this idea would expand to include other tables with different types of data, so I understand if you're wondering why I wouldn't just create a large table full of dates using a script, Excel, etc. I just thought the date dimension provided a good example to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think that will work, but you could probably accomplish the above using a trigger or using a package api to the table. Could you explain a bit more about what you intend to do with the table afterwards ? If the day_number and the day_name columns will never change from the equivalents in the date_key column, I don't really see the need for them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual columns for something like this. These are calculated on the fly based on the expression that defines the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE date_dim (
  Date_Key DATE NOT NULL,
  Day_Number AS (EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date_Key)),
  Day_Name AS (TO_CHAR(Date_Key, 'FMDay'))
)
```

Some notes:

- I've generally found it easier to not specify the type for a virtual column. You can, but often something weird happens. Your table was no exception: Oracle complained about the `VARCHAR2(36)` for `Day_Name`, saying it should be at least `VARCHAR2(75)`.
- I used the [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) function to get the day number because I think it's more descriptive for this; you should use whatever you're most comfortable with.
- I used the format string `FMDay` for `Day_Name` because the `Day` format code returns a string that's the length of the longest day name (Wednesday in English), so all other day names will have trailing spaces. The `FM` format code does a lot of useful things, and one of them is to trim trailing spaces.